# String manipulation and ignoring part of string

Tags: c++, string, file-io

I have an input with the following from a text file using C++

> command1 5 #Create 5 box
>   length 12
>   insertText THIS IS A BOX

how can i read in the input while ignoring anything after the #sign?

for example output should be without #Create 5 box

```
command1  5
length    12
insertText THIS IS A BOX
```

EDIT:

I tried the following:

```
while(getline(myfile, line))
{
    istringstream readLine(line);
    getline(readLine, command, ' ');
    getline(readLine, input, '\0');
}
```

...but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What have you tried already ? Show us what you wrote and that doesn't work, and we might try to help.

Comment: There are many possibilites, including regular expressions, string splitting, etc. But looking at the text format you posted I guess you need a more sophisticated parser later on ...

Answer (score 1):

in your function where you check every character one by one, add this code: (pseudo code)

```
if(currChar == #){
    while(currChar != '\n'){
        getNextChar();// you arent saving it so youre ignoring it
    }
 }else{
    Char c = getNextChar();
    //now you can add this character to your output string
```

Answer (score 1):

The outer `while(getline(` and `istringsteam` are good, but after that you'd want to read a space-separated word into command, then perhaps one or more space-separated inputs after that: something like

```
std::string command, input;
std::vector<std::string> inputs;
if (readLine >> command && command[0] != '#')
{
    while (readLine >> input && input[0] != '#')
        inputs.push_back(input);
    // process command and inputs...
}
```

It's easier to use `>>` than `getline` to parse `readLine` because they set the stream failure state if they don't get at least one valid character, making the `[0]` indexing safe and dropping out cleanly for empty lines, or commands with no inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `std::getline()` like this:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs("file.txt");

    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(ifs, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);

        if(std::getline(iss, line, '#')) // only read up to '#'
        {
            // use line here
            std::cout << line << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
command1 5 
length 12
insertText THIS IS A BOX
```

Answer (score 0):

for example. You can use ignore(inputSize, "#") or you can use getline
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/